# Vetenskapsrådet (the Swedish Research Council) international post doc - criteria

Tags: funding, postdocs, sweden

I'm currently working on finding some funding opportunities for a post doc project. I'm currently in my final (4th) year of my PhD in Uppsala (Sweden) studying evolutionary biology. I'm looking to do a post-doctoral project (in the UK).

Vetenskapsrådet - the Swedish Research Council - offers a fund for [International Post Doctoral](http://www.vr.se/inenglish/researchfunding/fundinggranted/internationalpostdoc.4.1d68133213a3f73f1e998a.html) positions of two years abroad and one year repatriation in Sweden.

I am struggling to find any information about qualifying criteria, can anyone offer some insights about who can apply and what can be applied for? I have two questions right now...

1) Is it required that the PhD must be attained before applications are made or can I apply before being awarded my PhD?

2) Is the fund open to people without Swedish citizenship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this information is made available on the webpage once each call for applications has been issued.

On this webpage [here](http://www.vr.se/inenglish/researchfunding/applyforgrants/callforproposals/closedgrants/internationalpostdoc.5.70a7940b146b8f93794b536a.html) you can find this year's call for applications. Or you can visit [vr.se/inenglish](http://vr.se/inenglish) and follow the links to Research Funding > Apply for Grants > Call for proposals > Closed call for proposals, all past funding rounds are listed.

The last round of applications closed on 2 September, so you'll have to wait until next year. It looks like you need your PhD before the closing date. I can't see a specific mention of citizenship as a requirement (you can always email the research council).

Comment: Thanks, appears that the requirement is that the PhD is from a Swedish university, and awarded before the closing date for applications (they have calls twice per year)